# What value to convert in getAsObject() & getAsString() methods of JSF Converter class

Tags: java, jsf, primefaces

I'm using PrimeFaces `autocomplete` with pojos, that shows results of a search. My code as follows:

```xml
 <p:autoComplete id="searchBar" completeMethod="#{search.fetchSuggestions}" value="#{search.selectedSuggestion}" 
                 var="searchResult" itemLabel="#{searchResult.entityName}" itemValue="#{searchResult.entityId}" converter="searchResultsConverter" >
      <p:column>  
           <p:graphicImage value="/images/#{searchResult.entityDisplayPic}" width="40" height="50"/>  
      </p:column>  

      <p:column>  
           #{searchResult.entityName}  
      </p:column>  
 </p:autoComplete>
```

What values do I need to convert in the `getAsObject()` and `getAsString()` methods in the converter class?

---

My `searchResult` class looks like this:

```
public class SearchResult {//object that hold the data of a single search result
    private int entityId;// may be userId/ groupId or etc etc in different cases
    private String entityName;
    private String entityDisplayPic; 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The goal of a [Converter](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E17802_01/j2ee/j2ee/javaserverfaces/1.1_01/docs/api/javax/faces/convert/Converter.html) is converting from a string representation to a concrete object and vice-versa. So in this case you need a String that uniquely identifies/describes your SearchResult object. It's really up to you what this string representation looks like. It might an aggregation of the fields used in the class, it might be an unique identifier that enables you to load the concrete object from some other (database)resource.

Comment: @M Platvoet: *Thanks!* I am passing the `primaryId` of search results (into the `itemValue` attribute of `autocomplete`) which uniquely identifies it. Thus, inside the `getAsObject()` method, do I need to identify which of the searchresult object corresponds to that primaryId string & return that corresponding search result object?

Answer (score 0):

I have converters in my webapp that "convert" between a retrieved database entity (I'm using JPA entities) and a string.  An example would be when I'm populating a drop-down list box in a form.  In this case, the string returned from the `getAsString()` method just an integer-based primary key for the JPA entity (converted to a string). The `getAsObject()` method then just needs to do a simple database lookup using the primary key to get the object.

The point is, your value from `getAsString()` just needs to contain enough info to allow your server-side code to get back a unique object. How you implement `getAsObject()` is totally up to you. Sometimes it's trivial and sometimes it's not.